# fields that don't match

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 3 fields per row in table 1 that I want to compare to the exact same fields per row in table 2

I have been playing around with NOT IN, but I am not having any luck. Can anyone help?

Basically I want to see all records from both tables where field 1, field 2, field 3 don't match in table 2

How would this be written?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN   Table2 T2
       ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
       AND T1.col2 = T2.col2
       AND T1.col3 = T2.col3
WHERE  T1.col1 <> T2.col1
       OR T1.col2 <> T2.col2
       OR T1.col3 <> T2.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

jyparask's answer is close, but it may not work if some of your columns are nullable and the where clause is off a bit.  In that case you need to either coalesce the columns to a value they couldn't actually contain, or check for nulls manually.

I'm going to assume col1 is not nullable, and cols 2 and 3 are

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN   Table2 T2
       ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
       AND (T1.col2 = T2.col2 or (T1.col2 is null and T2.col2 is null))
       AND (T1.col3 = T2.col3 or (T1.col3 is null and T2.col3 is null))
WHERE  T1.col1 is null or T2.col1 is null   # assuming col1 is not null
```

Or with a coalesce:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN   Table2 T2
       ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
       AND COALESCE(T1.col2,-1) = COALESCE(T2.col2,-1)
       AND COALESCE(T1.col3,-1) = COALESCE(T2.col3,-1)
WHERE  T1.col1 is null or T2.col1 is null   # assuming col1 is not null
```